# can't run application with qt-creator on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, qt-creator, nvidia

when I try to run a QtQuick application from QtCeator, I got this errors:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
QRhiGles2: Failed to create temporary context
QRhiGles2: Failed to create context
Failed to create RHI (backend 2)
Failed to initialize graphics backend for OpenGL
```

after investigation, I think the problem is Nvidia Driver because I have no problem with Nouveau Driver (the problem only exist with QtCreator)

for information:

```
ldd Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator | grep libGL
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fcdf5a19000)
```

and:

```
find /usr -iname "*libGL.so*" -exec ls -l -- {} + 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  439868 nov.  24 11:55 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 janv. 10 18:29 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib -> libGL.so.1.7.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1075136 déc.  11  2019 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.340.108
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 févr.  8  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 févr.  8  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.340.108
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  547152 nov.  24 11:55 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 janv. 10 18:29 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib -> libGL.so.1.7.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1267800 janv. 10 23:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.340.108
```

Thanks for your help